# Mongo find query via function in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have documents in Mongo in the form of:

```
{
"videoname": "TheTitle",
"numviews": "150"
}
```

I want to find all the documents with views greater than 1000. I can't use `$gt` because it doesn't work for strings, and I've tried with `$where`, but that returns all the documents in the collection.

```
let cursor = collection.find({$where: function(){return  Number(this.numviews) > 1000;}});
    cursor.count(function (err, count) {
      console.log("Total matches: " + count);
    });
```

So how can I accomplish this?

Comment: why is a numerical value a string?

Comment: @KevinB it's data from the Youtube API, which happens to be a string

Comment: While slow, that `$where` query should work. But you really should convert the strings to a number type before storing them in mongodb.

Comment: @JohnnyHK For context, this came from from another ( now deleted ) question from the OP about `$where` syntax with the node.js driver. My prompt to them then was to rather post a new question showing how they were using `$where` since *"you almost never really need it"*. So it is indeed "hoped" that the lesson learned here was to actually **convert the data** rather than persist using `$where`

Answer (score -1):

Ideally, convert the data!

But in the short term, I think mongo supports regex. So how about a `where` clause like:

```
{numViews: /[1-9][0-9]{3,}/}
```